# How to iterate KeyValue List and how to read key from console and display its value on console in C#

Tags: c#

I'm  storing some City names as a Key and its zipcode as value in a KeyValuePair list and trying  to read key from console as a user input and want to display its vale on console. Can someone please help me to achieve this.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> City = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> (){
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Ind", "1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Aus", "2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Pak","3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Eng","4"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("USA","5")

};            
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in City)
{               
    Console.WriteLine("Enter City name or Zipcode");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input == kvp.Key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Zipcode of {0} is:{1}", 
        input, kvp.Value);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Zipcode of {0} is: {1}", 
        input, kvp.Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your code is doing. Why do you have an If statement at all if both branches have the exact same code? Why are you asking for user input if you're just going to ignore that input and show existing stored values?

Comment: Why not use a `Dictionary` instead of `List`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actual am still learning and i want to store some data(City and zip-code) in list, when i enter city(Key) as a user input it should display zip-code(Value) of that city. (Please ignore block of codes which is below else)

Comment: Your message says : *"Enter City name **or Zipcode**"*, not *"Enter City name"*

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary is used in place of List. Also, the while loop is an infinite loop, instead of looping on the items in the list.
Try:

```
     Dictionary<string, string> City = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     City.Add("Ind", "1");
     City.Add("Aus", "2");
     City.Add("Pak", "3");
     City.Add("Eng", "4");
     City.Add("USA", "5");


     while (true)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter City name. Press x to Exit");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "x")
           return;
        if (!City.TryGetValue(input, out string zipCode))
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid City");

        Console.WriteLine("Zipcode of {0} is:{1}", input, zipCode);
     }
```

Comment: The message says : *"Enter City name **or Zipcode**"*, not *"Enter City name"*

Comment: Thanks @Cid. edited the message string. As per OP, the requirement is : `trying to read key from console as a user input and want to display its vale on console`

Comment: How can i achieve vise versa i mean like  if i give value then it should show its key also but both logic should exist in the same loop. And also if i enter L or something like that it should show all the keys(Cities) that are stored in dictionary, how can i do this?

Comment: @sughoshbhat, I would encourage you to take a stab at it yourself. you could see the if condition in the code that looks for value in the dictionary. Try to search and find how to get key from a dictionary given a value in C#. Also, to list down the Cities, search for how to loop thru Dictionary keyvaluepairs.